# Public Static HashTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, hashtable

I have defined a `public static HashTable`. It stores data for a few seconds of runtime, and then data disappears, and then the `HashTable` becomes `null`.

What is the issue and how do I solve it?

Comment: Can you post some code? There's not enough to go on here......

Comment: Question is not useful -- can't figure out anything from the description

Comment: If the static hashtable variable is only assigned to in the constructor, make it `public static readonly`.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is you setting the hashtable to null somewhere.

Comment: How does the OP expect us to answer the question? Do they even think?

Comment: Not sure why this got closed and not just waiting for more clarification as BFree suggested? After all, the question itself is simple: A public static Hashtable in an ASP.net MVC application becomes NULL all the time. From that clear description we can explain that in ASP.net, static is shared across ALL requests for the entire lifetime of the application and ask for some code: How is the Hashtable declared? is there any code that creates it or sets it to NULL? The question isn't great and somewhat incomplete, but it is a real question IMHO...

Comment: (Edit: I meant ASP.net, not MVC. Seems I can't write ASP.net anymore without always adding MVC :))

Comment: @Michael Did you take a look at the first incarnation of the question, before Kyle's editing?

Comment: @belisarius Yes. The first one had bad English, which could have been easily corrected, but it had details needed to understand the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

The web application has restarted then.

Completely expected behavior.

Find the cause that is restarting the web application.

It could be one of many things:

- Update web.config
- Recycling
- Any updates to .aspx files causing a recompilation.
- etc